# Create a for loop that saves an output into a variables that exist in a list? R

Tags: r, dplyr

This seemed very simple but its kind of been a blocker.

I have the following data frame

```
data <- data.frame("Number" = c(1,8,3,6),
                      "Name" = c("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Orange")
                      )

> print(data)
  Number   Name
1      1   Blue
2      8    Red
3      3  Green
4      6 Orange
```

My goal is have a for loop that uses a function on the value of `data$Number` and saves the output as a object with the values of `data$Name`.

Here is the simple function I have

```
for(x in data$Number) {
  print(x * 2) 
}


[1] 2
[1] 16
[1] 6
[1] 12
```

My goal would be to have something like this

```
Blue = 2
Red = 16
Green = 6
Orange = 12
```

Here is the code I tried but didn't work as intended as it just deletes the previous value saved

```
for(x in data$Number) {
  print(x * 2) 
  y <- data %>% filter(Number == x) %>% select(Name)
   y$Name  <-(x * 2)
}
```

Comment: Would it potentially make more sense to store it in a dataframe with a "colour" property instead?  Or does it _have_ to be variable names for the colors?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to have multiple objects, but here is an option

```
library(collapse)
> data$Name %=% (data$Number * 2)
> Blue
[1] 2
> Red
[1] 16
> Green
[1] 6
> Orange
[1] 12
```

---

Or using a pipe

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
data %>% 
  select(2:1) %>%
  deframe %>% 
  magrittr::multiply_by(2) %>%
  as.list %>% 
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(data$Number)) assign(data$Name[i], data$Number[i] * 2)
```